# Add column with default in postgresql without table level lock

Tags: postgresql, performance, alter-table, postgresql-performance

Have such a problem - table with over 20mln rows.

When i add new column with default - postgresql lock table for over 40 minutes so my application stop working for this time.

So instead of

```
ALTER TABLE "test" ADD COLUMN "field" boolean DEFAULT True NOT NULL;
```

I do

```
ALTER TABLE "test" ADD COLUMN "field" boolean NULL;
ALTER TABLE "test" ALTER COLUMN "field" SET DEFAULT true;
```

after which every new row will be with true by default, so now i need to update 20mln current rows.
I update them in batches:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id as pk
FROM "test"
WHERE  "field" is null
LIMIT  10000
)
UPDATE "test" table_
SET "field" = true
FROM   cte
WHERE  table_.id = cte.pk
```

after which i do

```
ALTER TABLE "test" ALTER COLUMN "field" SET NOT NULL;
```

And everything is allwright but step when i update rows is so much slow. Can you give my some advice about improving speed of update?

Currently it update 10000 in about 2 minutes.
I try decreasing size to 1000 - it was better (3.5 minutes for 10000) but it still to slow.
I also try create index before update, but it doesnt give better results (as i understand it will give better result but when huge path of table will be updated).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem is solved in PostgreSQL 11, which was released on October 18, 2018.

There is a more detailed explanation [in this blog post](https://www.depesz.com/2018/04/04/waiting-for-postgresql-11-fast-alter-table-add-column-with-a-non-null-default/), but the short version is that in Version 11 the table doesn't have to be rewritten to add a default value to a column. So adding a column with a default should be pretty much instant.

Answer (score 4):

All you can do now is,

1. Create a column that is `NULLABLE`
2. `ALTER` the column to give it the `DEFAULT`
3. UPDATE in batches to rewrite the rows (row-level locking)
4. When the rows are updated, add the `NOT NULL` constraint (which should be pretty quick just a seq scan.

For more information, [*see this answer*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216153/2639)